# Can I ask this question related to Steve Jobs in the main site?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask a question in the main site to users about their best quote or memories from ***Steve Jobs***. This would be way off-topic from the approved list of topics in the site.

I wanted to double check since we are talking about ***Steve Jobs*** here :)

Comment: Are the down voters upset that this is being asked (or the form of the question) or just voting instead of answering no to the question? I thought the practice is to up vote a relevant question even if the answer to that question is no.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Main Site:

This question isn't really asking a question about Apple hardware and software, so it's inherently off-topic.

What's more, it would have to be a Community Wiki since there is no one 'right answer'.
The current attitude about CW is generally against (see [How to kill off 'community wiki' entries](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-to-kill-off-community-wiki-entries) and [The future of community wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)).

Since this wouldn't be a particularly educational CW, nor relevant to the core of this site (questions about Apple hardware and software), I personally don't think it should be posted on the main site.

### Meta Site:

Since this isn't, in any way, a question about the main site itself, it should not be posted on Meta.

### Other Option:

I think that this would be  an interesting post. However, I don't believe that it would be a good fit for our Q&A site.

If you're interested in getting the Ask Different community to discuss Steve Jobs, I think your best option is to **create a chat room for it**.
Chat rooms have much looser scope than the rest of the site, and are especially designed for discussion.